# Why the favicon is different on the other pages

Tags: html, css, image, favicon

I have a the home page which has a favicon which is transparent [here](http://posnation.com/) but on the other pages on the site the is a favicon with a outer white [here](http://posnation.com/pre_config/step2/Retail_System)

How is that possible if its the same favicon ...or is it different...i am viewing source and they appear to be pulling from the same location...could it be css related

Comment: CSS won't let you set the favicon.

Answer (score 5):

You are setting two different icons in inner pages:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/pre_config/css/images/favicon.ico" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I navigate these sites, with Google Chrome and IE8 and both icons are transparent.

Maybe, its a local cache.

Answer (score 0):

They both look the same to me (Chrome).

I've found that favicon sometimes takes a while to propagate through caches, etc. There's no mechanism to set different icons for different pages. I suspect you just need to wait, or try a different browser that doesn't have the old images cached.